# Disable functions/aliases in a sourced script

Tags: bash, function, alias

I know I can run an "original" command (not alias) using either `\` or `""`:

```
\ls
"ls"
```

This doesn't work for functions though. Also it requires me to use that syntax every time.

Is it possible in a sourced script to disable all functions/aliases from the parent process (one which runs my script)? I.e. if a user in their terminal has some aliases functions defined I want them disabled in my script (but of course I still want to be able to define and use aliases/functions of my own).

Comment: Aliases and functions from the parents process should have no effect in your script unless you export the funcitons or source the script.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mentioned it's a sourced script, my bad. I've edited the question.

Comment: You could prefix everything with `builtin` or `command` (see `help builtin` and `help command`), but right know I cannot think of a way to do this automatically in a sourced script without altering the "parent" environment or loosing the benefits of a sourced script.

Comment: The sane solution is probably to not source your script, and instead have it print something the caller has to trust and `eval`.

Comment: @Socowi Make your comment an answer - if no one comes up with anything better I'll accept it. Also please explain the difference between `builtin` and `command` in this case, if possible.

Comment: @tripleee Normally, I avoid sourcing scripts but it's not an option in my case.

Comment: I think you can disable expansion of all aliases with `\shopt -u expand_aliases`. You can later reenable alias expansion with `\shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Types of Commands in Bash

Bash knows different types of commands which can shadow each other. The precedence of these types is:

- aliases
  *can be defined by the user using `alias cmd=...`*
- functions
  *can be defined by the user using `cmd() { ... }`*
- built-ins
  *are directly implement in bash and cannot be altered. `help` and `enable` list all built-ins.*
- Executable files in `$PATH`

Meaning if you type `cmd arg1 arg2 ...` you use the alias `cmd` if it is defined, otherwise you use the function `cmd` if it is defined, otherwise you use the built-in `cmd` if it is built-in, otherwise you use the first executable `cmd` from the directories in `$PATH` if there is one, otherwise you end up with the error `-bash: cmd command not found`.

Which of these cases applies for `cmd` can be checked using `type -a cmd`.

#### Manual Precedence Control

Bash allows you to influence which type to pick using quoting and the built-ins `command` and `builtin`.

- `\cmd`
  suppresses aliases
  uses functions, built-ins, executables
- `command cmd`
  suppresses aliases and functions
  uses built-ins and executables
- `builtin cmd`
  supresses aliases, functions, and executables
  uses only built-ins
- `enable -n cmd`
  disables the built-in `cmd` completely, such that afterwards only
  aliases, functions, and executables are used
- `env cmd`
  not a bash built-in, therefore it doesn't really suppress anything but
  uses only executables

#### Examples

Shadowing is perfectly normal. For instance, bash has its own built-in `echo`, but your system also has `/bin/echo`. Both implementations may differ. For instance, my `echo` from bash 5 supports `\uXXXX` but my `echo` from GNU coreutils 8.3 does not. The possibility of such differences becomes even more clear if you add your own implementations using aliases and functions. Here's an example in an interactive bash session (`$`  is the prompt):

```
$ echo() { printf "function echo: %s\n" "$*"; }
$ alias echo='printf "alias echo: %s %s %s\n"'
$ type -a echo
echo is aliased to `printf "alias echo: %s %s %s\n"'
echo is a function
echo ()
{
    printf "function echo: %s\n" "$*"
}
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo

$ echo -e '\u2261'
alias echo: -e \u2261
$ \echo -e '\u2261'
function echo: -e \u2261
# use the built-in (or executable file if there was no such built-in)
$ command echo -e '\u2261'
≡
$ builtin echo -e '\u2261'
≡

# use the executable /bin/echo
$ env echo -e '\u2261'
\u2261

$ enable -n echo
# use the executable /bin/echo (`command` is needed to skip the alias and function)
$ command echo -e '\u2261'
\u2261
```

#### Answering your Question

Unfortunately I'm not aware of something like `enable` to permanently disable alias and function lookup. You could try some hacks like backing up all aliases and functions, doing `unset -f` and `unalias` on them, and restoring them at the end. However, `unset` may fail for readonly functions. The better way would be to use `bash -c '... functions and aliases have no effect here ...'` for the parts where you don't really need the benefits of `source`. For the other parts, prefix everything with `command`.

**Please note:** The caller who sources your script may even disable or shadow `command`, `builtin`, and so on -- therefore you can never be sure that you are actually using the commands you expected. Even writing `/usr/bin/env executable` or `/path/to/the/executable` does not help as a function can have the name and `$PATH` or the file system can be altered.
However, that shouldn't be your concern. The one who sources your script should be responsible for providing the correct environment.

Comment: An excellent answer! A nitpick, though, is that [the POSIX `env` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) says that, if the argument to `env` is a built-in, the results are undefined. So it might be incorrect to say `env` "uses only executables".

Comment: Thank you, what a strange little detail. I leave that out of this answer to keep it simple. But thanks to your comment, the information is there for everyone.

Comment: Such a beautiful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer might no longer be relevant since you edited the question to clarify that the script is being sourced, not being executed in a subshell.

---

This happens by default. Proof:

```
$ function x() { echo 'hi'; }
$ x
hi
$ bash
# We are now in a subshell.
$ x
bash: x: command not found
```

Functions are often defined in one of the shell's startup files: `.bashrc`, `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. Which of these are sourced depends on whether the shell is a *login* shell and/or an *interactive* shell. A shell that invoked to execute a shell script is neither a login shell nor an interactive shell, and in this case none of those files are sourced.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I should read more carefully, as you don't want to source a script, but be sourced, the following is for the other way around:

### Functions

If you source your parent script at the beginning, you can just loop through the defined functions and unset them.

`declare -F` will list all defined functions but in the format `declare -f functioname`, so you have to get only the name:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(declare -F|cut -d ' ' -f 3); do
    unset -f $f
done
```

### Aliases

Alias should not be sourced in as i remember, but if they are there you can do

```
unalias -a
```

to unset them all.